# Iterating through a specific testcase in nighwatch

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I am new to nightwatch & found it very helpful in automating the tests. However, I have come across a problem & am unable to find a solution. Please help me out on this.

Consider following code:

```
module.exports = {
    'testcase1' : function(browser) {
        //GET SOME LINKS HERE DYNAMICALLY
    },

    'testcase2' : function(browser) {
        //FOR EACH OF THE LINKS OBTAINED IN 'testcase1', DO THE FOLLOWING:
        //OPEN THE LINK, CLICK ON A PARTICULAR ELEMENT(I KNOW THE ELEMENT HERE, SO THATS NOT AN ISSUE) & TAKE A SCREENSHOT    
    } 
};
```

So I will be getting some links dynamically & I want to run 'testcase2' on each of them, **without affecting each other's execution**. I tried loops but that doesn't help since javascript is **asynchronous**.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do loops is to loop over commands. Nightwatch keeps track of the order of commands and maintains it for you. This will make it chainable from one command to the next.

Put the get links code that is used in both tests into a command. Also put the code to use the links in a different command.

Commands can be in their own folder or created within Page objects. Assuming you go with creating a commands folder, add the folder path to the top of nightwatch.json like this `"custom_commands_path" : "commands",`

Then create the files. They can look like this:

```
// put this command in a file named 'getLinks'
exports.command = function() {
    var self = this;
    var globals = self.globals;

    //do stuff to get links
    //make links accessible by other commands
    globals.links = links;

    return self;
};

// put this command in file named 'useLinks'
exports.command = function() {
    var self = this;
    var links = self.globals.links;

    // note you don't have to use _.js here. 'for (var i; i < links.length...' works fine too.
    _.each(links, function (link) {
        //do something with the link
        self.url('theUrlWithTheLinks')
            .click(link)
            //use commands for each thing to do 
            //this way it is chainable and order is maintained
            .click(someElement)
            .takeTheNeededScreenshot();
    })
    return self;
};

//tests
module.exports = {
    'testcase1' : function(browser) {
        //GET SOME LINKS HERE DYNAMICALLY
        browser.getLinks()
    },

    'testcase2' : function(browser) {   
        browser.getLinks()
            .useLinks()
            //chain more commands
            .end();

    } 
};
```